# Cannot insert data into database CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert a data into database, when I insert data and press submit button, the text field are just got empty and data couldn't been inserted into database
As I see from my code everything look like OK, but where I made mistake ?

**Post Controller**

```
<?php


class Posts extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();

    }

    public function index($page='home'){

        $data['posts']= $this->Posts_model->get_posts();

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function view($mjestoOdredista=NULL){


        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($mjestoOdredista);
        $post_id = $data['posts']['id'];
        $data['comments'] = $this->comment_model->get_comments($post_id);




        if(empty($data['posts'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['id'] =$data['posts'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/view',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function create(){
        //check if user is logged in
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('users/login');
        }

        $data['title'] ='Create Posts';
        $data['categories'] = $this->Posts_model->get_categories();



        if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE){

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('posts/create',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }else {

            //upload image
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048';
            $config['max_width'] = '500';
            $config['max_height'] = '500';

            $this->load->libary('upload', $config);

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
                $error=array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
                $post_image='noimage.jpg';
            }else{
                $data = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
                $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            }
            $this->Posts_model->create_post($post_image);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('post_creted', 'You post has been created') ;
            redirect('posts');
        }

    }

    public function delete($id){

        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('users/login');
        }


        $this->Posts_model->delete_post($id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_deleted', 'You post has been deleted  ') ;
        redirect('posts');
    }



    public function edit($mjestoOdredista){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('users/login');

        }

        $data['mjestoOdredista']= $this->Posts_model->get_posts($mjestoOdredista);

        //Check if user is logged in
        if($this->session->userdata('user_id') !=$this->Posts_model->get_posts($mjestoOdredista)['user_id'])
            redirect('posts');
        $data['categories'] = $this->Posts_model->get_categories();

        if(empty($data['mjestoOdredista'])){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['id'] = 'Edit Post';
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/edit',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function update(){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('users/login');
        }

        $this->Posts_model->update_post();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'You post has been updated ') ;
        redirect('posts');

    }

    }

?>
```

**Post Model**

```
<?php


class Posts_Model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database();

    }

    function get_posts($mjestoOdredista=FALSE){
        if($mjestoOdredista === FALSE){

            $this->db->order_by('posts.id','DESC');
            $this->db->join('categories','categories.id = posts.category_id');
            $query=$this->db->get('posts');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query=$this->db->get_where('posts', array('mjestoOdredista' => $mjestoOdredista));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    //Kreiranje post
    public function create_post($post_image){
        $mjestoPolaska = url_title($this->input->post('title'));
        $data=array(
                'mjestoPolaska' => $mjestoPolaska,
                'mjestoOdredista' => $this->input ->post('Mjesto Odredista'),
                'datumPolaska' => $this->input ->post('Datum Polaska'),
                'datumPovratka' => $this->input ->post('Datum Povratka'),
                'brojMjesta' => $this->input ->post('Broj Mjesta'),
                'cijena' => $this->input ->post('cijena'),
                'opis' => $this->input ->post('Opis'),
                'category_id'=>$this->input->post('category_id'),
                'user_id' =>$this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'post_image'=>$post_image

        );

        return $this->db->insert('posts',$data);
    }

    //Brisanje posta
    public function delete_post($id){
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('posts');
        return true;
    }


    //editovanje posta
    public function update_post(){
        $mjestoPolaska=url_title($this->input->post('Mjesto Polaska'));
        $data=array(
                'mjestoPolaska' => $mjestoPolaska,
                'mjestoOdredista' => $this->input ->post('Mjesto Odredista'),
                'datumPolaska' => $this->input ->post('Datum Polaska'),
                'datumPovratka' => $this->input ->post('Datum Povratka'),
                'brojMjesta' => $this->input ->post('Broj Mjesta'),
                'cijena' => $this->input ->post('cijena'),
                'opis' => $this->input ->post('Opis'),
                'category_id'=>$this->input->post('category_id'),
                'user_id' =>$this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'post_image'=>$post_image

        );
        $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'));
        return $this->db->update('posts',$data);

    }

    public function get_categories(){
        $this->db->order_by('name');
        $query = $this->db->get('categories');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_posts_by_category($category_id){

        $this->db->order_by('posts.id','DESC');

        $this->db->join('categories','categories.id = posts.category_id');
        $query=$this->db->get_where('posts',array('category_id'=>   $category_id));
        return $query->result_array();

    }

}



?>
```

**View**

```
<h2><?= $title;?></h2>
<!--  jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Isolated Version of Bootstrap, not needed if your site already uses Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />
<!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>



<?php echo form_open_multipart('posts/create');?>
<?php echo validation_errors();?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mjesto Polaska</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mjesto_polaska" placeholder="Mjesto Polaska">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mjesto Odredista</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mjesto_odredista" placeholder="Mjesto Odredista">
                </div>

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Datum Polaska</label>
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function () {
                                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>      

                                    <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Datum Povratka</label>
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function () {
                                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>  




                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Cijena</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cijena" placeholder="Cijena">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
              <label for="sel1">Broj slobodnih mjesta:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                  </select>
                </div>


            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Kategorije">Kategorija</label>
            <div>
            <select name="category_id" class="form_control">
            <?php foreach($categories as $category):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category['id'];?>"><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
             <label>Postavi sliku:</label>
             <p><b>samo oni koji nude prevoz nek postave sliku svojeg vozila</b></p>
             <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="comment">Opis:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                <?php form_close();?>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should read the documentation and perform the included tutorial examples.

Comment: What do you mean by documentation ? @Sparky

Comment: [Definition of "Documentation"](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&q=definition+of+%22documentation%22&oq=definition+of+%22documentation%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i30k1l2j0j0i7i30k1j0l6.6046.6046.0.6966.1.1.0.0.0.0.217.217.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.1.217.ljeLYcvt67M)

Comment: Here:  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: And what now ? Why do you need documentation ?

Comment: *"Why do you need documentation?"*  ~ Ironic.

Comment: What now?  Read it all... follow the included example project.  It only takes a few hours from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I see you entered the inputs name incorrect
change your inputs name in the model from

`$this->input->post('mjesto odredista')` To `$this->input->post('mjesto_odredista')` .etc

make sure your all inputs in the view = your inputs in the model .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your **MODEL** and **VIEW**.

In the **MODEL**, when you are calling `$this->input->post('Mjesto Odredista')` inside the `()` you have to give name of the input field. I think here you have given the `placeholder`.

When comes to **VIEW**, for some of the input field you have not given the `name` attribute like `Datum Povratka` , `Broj slobodnih mjesta`, `Opis` etc. For example,

```
 <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Datum Povratka</label>
           <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                     </span>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```